# Context - unable to create external files directory

Tags: android, android-context, nexus-4

I have a very strange problem with my app that appears when you start app on the Nexus 4. 
I have following code in Application class:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    File dir = this.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    if (dir == null) {
        Log.e("App", "Problem with my dir!");
    }
}
```

In LogCat I saw message:

> 12-11 14:09:05.402 11739-11739/com.company.app W/ContextImpl: Unable to create external files directory 
>   12-11 14:09:05.402 11739-11739/com.company.app E/App: Problem with my dir!

I already have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Also, this problem appears only when I re-install my application and **don't reboot my device**. If I reboot my Nexus, problem disappear.

What can be wrong in this simple code snippet?..

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found cause of this strange behaviour.

In my application, after some initialization in `Application` class, I've started logging process like this:

```
String[] cmd = new String[] {
    "logcat", "-f", myFileNameFromExternalDir, "-v", "time"
};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

And **I didn't destroy this process** anywhere. That's why after re-intalling my app, Android unable to create external files dir or cache dir.

Summary:

1. If you started some process, don't forget to destroy it, e.g:

   Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
   ...
   process.destroy();
2. To check, if there are some unusual processes running on your device, you can use `adb shell`. For example:

*In Windows cmd*

**adb shell**

*In Android shell*

**ps** - it will list all processes on your device.

If you found something interesting, you can check, does this process belong to your application with `lsof` command:

**lsof -p *process_name* | grep *app_package***

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this way

```
File dir = new File (this.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/NewDirectory");  
if(!dir.exists()){
  f.mkdirs();// if there is no directory then create new
}
```

when use `getExternalFilesDir()` no need to add permission. its only needed when use `getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: Thank you, but this will not solved my problem. My initial task - get the path to the folder inside my application directory (it will be like this - /data/com.company.app/). But `this.getExternalFilesDir(null)` returns me `null` - and it is my problem. But problem disappear, when I reboot my device after re-installing my application.